# Importing Distance Matrix from Excel to Python

Tags: python, distance

I have the following distance matrix in Excel format.
[Excel Distance Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RNfN.png)

I need to convert it to python as a distance matrix. However, I can not achieve it right now.
Could you help me, please?
Thank you

Edit: [This is my code and how the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfmlE.png)

I need to use this output as distance matrix.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Can you please share a snippet of the code you tried, and explain what is the issue you are facing with it.- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the pic to my question how its look like. 

import pandas as pd
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model=pyo.ConcreteModel()
dataAddress=pd.read_excel("Google.xlsx", sheet_name="Addresses")
dataMatrix=pd.read_excel("Google.xlsx", sheet_name="Matrix")

This is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `pandas`:

- Anaconda environment: `conda install pandas`
- Python environment: `pip install pandas`

And load your file:

```
import pandas

df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

Read more:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-excel-files
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Would be helpful to give a source for further information : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-excel-files

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I can import the data from Excel. However, it's takes the matrix into different columns. 
I can not assign as matrix

Comment: Try `m = df.to_numpy()`. Now it's a matrix-like.

Comment: Thank you su much!